# Migrate All repositories from GitHub org to another GitHub Org (Same Instance)

Tags: git, github, migration

Looking for migrating/transferring All repositories from GitHub org to another GitHub Org  in the Same GitHub Instance. Is there anyone who tried this before ?

- Listing all repositories in the Org( It can be 10 or 1000+ )
- Moving them to another Org., transfer includes - All features of repos - Code History, PR's, Issues, Actions( secrets/Environments ), Branch Protection Rules

Please Suggest. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing

But there are 1000 repos that needs to be moved. Is there any way that we can achieve that ? Would that include everything - Issues/PRs/History/Actions incl secrets

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Transfer to automatically transfer the repos from one org to another](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/transferring-a-repository). There are APIs to do this using a script, instead of manually.

[List all repos](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-organization-repositories):

```
curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/repos
```

[Transfer a repo](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#transfer-a-repository):

```
curl -L \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/transfer \
  -d '{"new_owner":"github","new_name":"octorepo"}
```

Comment: Does this also copy the issues?

Comment: It doesn't copy, it moves the whole repo verbatim to the other organization.

Comment: See: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/transferring-a-repository

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing But there are 1000 repos that needs to be moved. Is there any way that we can achieve that ? Would that include everything - Issues/PRs/History/Actions incl secrets –

Comment: Have you checked the docs? Have you tried?

Comment: I'm suggesting you wrap the two calls in a small piece of script, that shouldn't be too hard. Can either be a PowerShell script or bash, python or anything else that can call a rest API and parse Json.